# Iphone app that displays a quick message, Is it possible?

Tags: iphone, xcode

A question for the Iphone app experts:

Imagine an app in which: You write some text and click a button "Show every 30 seconds". The app goes to the background. Every 30 seconds the text you wrote appears briefly.

Is it possible? I read about Local Notifications that may do the trick but that shows a popup and the user must click a button to close it, which is no good.

Any ideas?

Comment: im not sure if the api is available, but what about something along the lines of how the alarm works. you can set the snooze and the alarm dialog pops back up every so often

Comment: well the problem is that you have to click the snooze. I would like to show the message and close it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible with a jailbroken iPhone, but otherwise, no. Local notifications are your best bet for a standard iPhone.

Comment: Reading a little bit more I found: Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Comment: Maybe declaring the "audio" key and playing a silent audio will keep the app in background and using a timer, popup the message and close it. Sneaky but could work?

Comment: Maybe, but that’ll get rejected by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

not sure that you can tell something "every 30 secs"
but you could use local notification for 1 message, maybe more, but surely not have a **"loop"**

here there's some code sample from apple:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html